# load image and then animate it with canvas/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm completely new when it comes to canvas. I'm trying to draw an image onto the canvas and then animate it. Right now I'm having trouble drawing the image on screen. The image doesn't show at all.

Here part of the code:

```
var car = new Image();
car.src = "http://i.imgur.com/8jV4DEn.png";
car.x = 40; car.y = 60;

function draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(car.src, car.x, car.y);
}
```

[**Full fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/djt6V/1/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code.

- You have no `onload` handler
- You are using `x` and `y` properties on the image element - these are read-only properties
- You are using the image element instead of a custom object to add properties
- You are intending to call `draw` instead of `animate`
- You are not clearing the background of the canvas for each draw
- You are trying to draw the image using its url
- The poly-fill should be outside the loop
- The `reqAnimFrame` poly doesn't acknowledge non-prefixed `requestAnimationFrame`.
- And the car goes side-ways.. :-)

Here is adjusted code and a **[modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/djt6V/4/)**:

```
var reqAnimFrame = 
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

var car = new Image();

/// when image is loaded, call this:
car.onload = animate;

/// x and y cannot be used, in "worse" case use this but ideally
/// use a custom object to set x and y, store image in etc.
car._x = 40;
car._y = 60;
car.src = "http://i.imgur.com/8jV4DEn.png";

var speed = 5;

function animate(){

    car._y += speed;

    draw();
    reqAnimFrame(animate);
}

function draw(){

    /// clear background
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    /// cannot draw a string, draw the image:
    ctx.drawImage(car, car._x, car._y);
}

/// don't start animate() here
//animate();
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately - mind showing me using the fiddle I included? :)

Comment: @Nilzone- please see updated answer, the post was a bit misleading compared to the fiddle :)

Comment: Thank you very much for a super-clear answer :) I still got a lot of stuff to learn

Comment: Btw - Why should I not call animate()? I looked at a couple of guides where they have a draw and animate function. to start it all animate() is called. i.e. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/animation.html

Comment: @Nilzone- no problem. Don't call `animate` directly as your image isn't loaded at the time (image loading is asynchronous in JavaScript). That's why you hand it to the `onload` handler instead (which will call it when image is loaded and can be used). Also see my update in the answer - I discovered another error with the requestAnimationFrame poly.

Comment: So with normal shapes, i.e a rectangle it would be okey to call animate()?

Comment: @Nilzone- yes, that will work as they are drawn synchronous (after the image has loaded it too will be drawn synchronous but when loading it the steps handling loading must be taken first).

Comment: Hey! One last question: I tried to update my code based on a couple of tutorials - now it stopped working - http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/djt6V/7/ In short i tried using immediately-invoked function on the requestAnimFrame